# How to make more columns in a while loop?

Tags: php

I have this code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        echo "
        <div><h4><a href=\"page.php?id={$row['subcategory_id']}\">{$row['subcategory']}</a></h4>
        </div>\n";

    }
```

With this while I put on a page a vertical line with subcategories. For ex:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

I want to limit those subcategories to 10 and after each 10 to start from the top again, like this:

```
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
```

Can someone tell how to do that?

Comment: It's more HTML than PHP problem. Use a table.

Comment: read all values by `$array = mysqli_fetch_all($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` then divide it to 3 arrays by array_chunk and output the same indexes of that 3 arrays

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: https://3v4l.org/MmWJA

And here's an example using your own code:

```
// get your array in a var
$array = mysqli_fetch_all($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// set column to 10 items tall
$col_height = 10; 

// count the array
$count = count($array);

// determine number of columns based on column height and array size
$row_len = $count / $col_height;

//create iterator
$i = 0;

// loop that shits
foreach($array as $row) {

    // added display = inline 
    echo "<div style='display:inline-block;'><h4><a href=\"page.php?id={$row['subcategory_id']}\">{$row['subcategory']}</a></h4></div>\n";

    // echo a line break only when needed, reset the iterator
    if($i == $row_len){
        echo "<br>";
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @kido - Welcome to SO, if this answer helps you be sure to hit the check mark by my answer to get your first two points. If you like, you can also upvote! Good luck!